# how to approve and disapprove campaign in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

I have Campaign List in admin side.
I want to approve and disapprove campaign.

[image]

my campaign schema:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('campaign', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine='InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('campaign_name');
            $table->float('campaign_goal',8,2);
            $table->string('discription',400);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->date('start_date');
            $table->date('end_date');
            $table->float('total_fund',8,2);
            $table->boolean('is_approved');
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

How to approve and disapprove campaign?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: You have to give action on buttons for call controller method...

Comment: i don't try anything..bcz i don't know how to do..@SmitRaval

Comment: i saw the code ...but i don't understand how it actually works..@PPL

Comment: is there any link given in action button or not...?

Comment: public function postApprove($id) 
    {
        $application = CreateFundRaiser::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
        print($application);
        exit();
        if($application)
        {
            $application->approved = 1;
            $application->save();
            return redirect()->back()->with('success','The application was approved successfully');
        }
    }  this is controller method @PPL

Comment: <a href="{{route('campaigns',['id'=>$campaign->id])}}" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:left;margin-left:25px">Approve</a>   this is button link @PPL

Comment: Route::post('/campaigns/approve{id}','CampaignController@postApprove'); @PPL

Comment: ok than what is the error...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put or define a segments delimiter on your route. `/` or `=`

```
Route::post('/campaigns/approve{id}','CampaignController@postApprove');
```

should be:

```
  Route::post('/campaigns/approve/{id}','CampaignController@postApprove');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AJAX request like below

**In Controller**

```
public function postUpdateApprovalStatus() {
  $campaign = Campaign::find((int)$request->input('id'));
  $campaign->is_approved = $request->input('approval_status');
  $campaign->save();
  return ['status'=> 200, 'message'=> "Campaign approval status updated successfully'];
}
```

**In View**

Add `data-campaign-id={campaign-id}` attribute to both approval and disapproval buttons in each row and also add class name as `approval` for both buttons.

And add `data-status="true"` for approval button and add `data-status="false"`  to disapproval button

Then

Add click event listener using `approval` class name

```
$('.approval').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '<hostname>/<controller-name>/update-approval-status',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {"id": $(this).data('campaign-id'), "approval_status": $(this).data('status')},
   datatype: 'application/json',
   success: function(response) {
     //display message here using response.message to appending to some div above the table
   }
  });
});
```